# How to get Connection information details?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am using Spring-Boot with JPA to access a MariaDB.

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?serverTimezone=Europe/Paris
spring.datasource.username = myuser
spring.datasource.password = mysecret
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
@Transactional
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository <MyRec, Long>
{
}
```

**MyComp.java**

```
@Component
public class MyComp
{
    @Autowired
    MyRepo mr;
   
    public void foo ()
    {
        MyRec rec = new MyRec ();
        rec.setName ("Sam");

        this.mr.save (rec);    // save to DB
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions

- How to obtain connection information abouth the DB?
- Lets say I use MariaDB galera with 2 hosts: How can I find out in the program to which one I am connected?

Comment: You must be reading those values by using `@Value` annotation by specifying keys, simple way would be to print those String variables in which you store ! The active ones or the ones which are picked up would be printed :) Or if you are not reading those values directly, you can use @Value to read those values from properties file , or specify a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Not what I have configured is what I want but what is in use by the application. So I think there must be a way I can get it out from JPA - I hope.

Comment: You can invoke `/health` endpoint of actuator, It will result something like`{"status":"UP","db":{"status":"UP","database":"PostgreSQL","hello":1}}` Check if that works

Answer (score 4):

You can inject the `DataSource` and get the `Connection` from there. Then you can access the `DatabaseMetaData`

```
@Component
public class AppRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public AppRunner(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have a failover connecthen then I see still both hosts in the URL. Any way to get the host to which I am connected?

Comment: I could query it by "SELECT @@hostname" but maybe that information is part of the connection too. Especially I want to know WHEN the connection switches to another host.

Comment: You can't because this is handled by the JDBC driver. Sou query for the information is the only way